# How to test nested $.when with Jasmine

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, tdd

What is the proper way to test with Jasmine the following?:

```
    $.when(this.collection1.fetch()).done(()=> {
        $.when(this.collection2.fetch({reset: true})).done(()=> {
            this.render();
        });
    });
```

I need to make sure that first the `this.collection1.fetch()` is finished before the second request started.

Comment: Do you really want to pass only one promise to `$.when()`? *Side note:* why are you using `$.when()` at all? This could be written `this.collection1.fetch().then(() => this.collection2.fetch({reset: true})).done(() => this.render())`. `$.when()` is fine to fulfill a promise after _all of multiple, parallel promises_ have fullfilled.

Comment: You are right, but I have also multiple cases where I do exactly what you mentioned - parallel promises. This is just an example with one promise.